# using javascript to generate an id to be an 'active state'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hope somebody can help.

I have a multi stage form with 4 sections and only one section showing at any time. You can move through the steps by clicking any of the four buttons 1 to 4. The html for these buttons doesnt change in the process, my question: is there anything that could be added in the javascript which would generate a class when a stage is clicked? eg

```
<p id="first" class="current">
```

giving me the chance to style it as an active state

---

the Buttons in the html are

```
<div>
  <p id="first"><span class="step">1</span><br /><br />Personal Details</p>
 <p id="second"><span class="step">2</span><br /><br />Quantity and Sizes</p>
 <p id="third"><span class="step">3</span><br /><br />Text, Cover and Finish</p>
 <p id="fourth"><span class="step">4</span><br /><br />Other</p>
 </div>
```

the javascript shows the relevant div and hides the rest

```
//relates to a prev next button at bottom of each stage
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#firstBtn").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#firstStep").hide();
     $("#secondStep").show();
     }
 });
 $("#secondBtn").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#thirdStep").show();
     $("#secondStep").hide();
     }
 });

 $("#thirdBtn").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#fourthStep").show();
     $("#thirdStep").hide();
     }
 });

 $("#fourthBtnBack").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#fourthStep").hide();
     $("#thirdStep").show();
     }
 });
 $("#thirdBtnBack").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#thirdStep").hide();
     $("#secondStep").show();
     }
 });
 $("#secondBtnBack").click(function(){
  if($("#loginForm").valid()){
     $("#secondStep").hide();
     $("#firstStep").show();
     }
 });

// the 1,2,3,4 click between stages

$("#first").click(function(){
     $("#firstStep").show();
     $("#secondStep,#thirdStep,#fourthStep").hide();

 });
 $("#second").click(function(){
     $("#thirdStep,#firstStep,#fourthStep").hide();
     $("#secondStep").show();
 });

 $("#third").click(function(){
     $("#fourthStep,#firstStep,#secondStep").hide();
     $("#thirdStep").show();
 });
 $("#fourth").click(function(){
     $("#fourthStep").show();
     $("#thirdStep,#firstStep,#secondStep").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Create a seperate click handler to add and remove class as

```
$("#first,#secondStep,#thirdStep,#fourthStep").click(function(){
     $('.active').removeClass('active'); //Remove active class from other elements
     $(this).addClass('active'); //Add active class on current element
});
```

Comment: Why not select all the buttons at once, rather than repeat the same code 4 times?

Comment: Thanks, this definately worked for me to add the "active" class, however clicking each stage doesnt do anything now (other than add the class). There is more code which it may be conflicting with, i've updated my original post.

Comment: @DesBank, The above code was just to mange the class, You need to add this event handler to your existing code

Comment: Thanks Satpal. The active state and functionality are working great. One thing which would be ideal is if stage one could be loaded as class "active" when the page is loaded? The active states don't take hold until you start clicking.

Comment: @DesBank Just use `$("#first").trigger('click')`